# Successfully installed texlive-full but can't find it

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, linux

Why is it that I can't find any icons or shortcuts of my LaTeX installation?

I installed it using this:

> `$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full.`

But when I look at my application, I can't locate it. When I tried to right click a `.tex` file and select the option of `Open with other application` just to find LaTeX/TeXworks,  I still can't see it.

Also checked the `/usr/share/texmf/` and all files are there.

I'm using 11.04 Natty.

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but I think `texlive-full` does not include TeXworks. You could try `sudo apt-get install texworks` to see if it works.

Comment: @PauloCereda Could you make your comment into an answer

Comment: @JosephWright: done. `:)`

Comment: additional question does listings package supports .css extension files?

Comment: You can see the contents of the texlive-full package here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/tex/texlive-full

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run `latex` from a shell. Try to make a minimal file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Then save it in your home directory as `test.tex` and in your shell type `pdflatex test`. It should produce the `test.pdf` file. If the PDF is not created, report here what failed.

Comment: tested it and it work. it gave me .pdf. But how can I have an IDE for this like Texworks? I thought installing texlive-full would give me an IDE like TexWorks.

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu so I can't help you specifically, but try to [check this TeXWorks page](https://launchpad.net/~texworks/+archive/stable) to get the IDE.

Comment: additional question does listings package supports .css extension files?

Comment: I really don't know. And since it is unrelated to the original question, you should make it a new question thread.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*(converting my comment to an answer)*</sub>

I'm not a Ubuntu user, but I think `texlive-full` does not include TeXworks. You could try to install it by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texworks
```

Then TeXworks will be available.

**Edit:** [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) mentioned that the "official" TeX Live does include TeXworks, but not the `texlive-full` repackaged for Ubuntu. Besides, Ubuntu still uses TL2009, which does not include TeXworks.

[matth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8569/matth) mentioned that TeXworks is already available from the Ubuntu repository, so the additional Launchpad PPA is not needed after all. Thanks! `:)`

Comment: TeXworks is part of the full 'vanilla' installation of TeX Live from the official site, but not of `texlive-full` as repackaged for Ubuntu. This may well be because Ubuntu uses TL2009, which did not include TeXworks.

Comment: TeXworks is available for Ubuntu, the Launchpad PPA is not needed: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/texworks

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, Joseph! I updated my answer. `:)`

Comment: @matth: Thanks, matth! I really had no idea that TeXworks was already in the Ubuntu repository. I removed the additional info about the Launchpad PPA. `:)`